# Using prio qdisc for voip

Tags: voip, qos

I have an [Ooma](http://ooma.com/products/ooma-telo) VoIP device on my home network.  I do not want it to act as the router to the internet as I already have a dual-nic linux box that is working just fine.  I do want to start using a priority qdisc to make all traffic from the ooma device as high priority, torrents as low priority, and everything else as normal priority.  I've tried a variety of settings and I must not be doing it quite right as everything I try dumps nearly all packets in the middle priority class.  On my linux box (CentOS 6) eth1 is the internal network and eth0 goes to the internet.

Thanks!

Comment: Try asking this in SuperUser or ServerFault